# Split output from one conveyor belt equally to five other conveyor belts.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

I was asked a question about the game "Satisfactory" and how to split an output into $5$ equal parts using "splitters" with one input and 2-3 outputs and mergers that accept 2-3 inputs.

A splitter accepts input from one conveyor belt and its output feeds two or three other conveyor belts. A merger accepts input from two or three conveyor belts and its output feeds a single conveyor belt.

$$\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}=\frac{c}{5}
\implies c = \frac{5 a}{2} + \frac{5 b}{3}$$

I'm out of ideas.  I'm beginning to think it's not possible. How do I split something into $5$ equal parts when I can only split/merge things by $2$s or $3$s?

Comment: I'm not thinking you can, but I'm not sure how to prove it. But basically if you're doing things symetrically, there's no way to get a $5$ out of multiplying and dividing $2$s and $3$s because they're all primes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your splitters and mergers are doing mathematically. Your final equations are easy to solve, 
eg $\frac22 + \frac33 = \frac{10}5$. If you're trying to solve $2^x3^y=5^z$ for nonzero integers $x,y,z$, that's impossible, as John mentioned.

Comment: Do you have a 2:2 splitter?  If so you can adapt designs used in factorial for this.

Comment: @Q the Platypus I don't know these games but $2:2$ is just a $2:1$ merge followed by a $1:2$ split. Could you explain what they do in "factorial"?

Comment: Please clarify what the 'splitter' and 'merger' do, and what their inputs and outputs are.

Comment: @Servaes I updated my question to explain splitter and merger.

Comment: You really need to finish fixing the question. I *think* I know what you want, but it's impossible, as we said earlier. But there are an infinite number of approximate solutions, eg 3/16, 7/36, 16/81, 65/324, etc. OTOH, if it's permitted to feed an output stream back into the original input, then it's do-able.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thank you for your corrections. I edited sloppily. I'm sure conveyors would be able to feed back into the original but I don't have any idea how to express that mathematically.

Comment: No need for any mathematical expression; split the original stream into six equal streams, and feed one back into the original. There are now only 5 output streams, and by symmetry they all output the same.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I did not downvote you.

Comment: @ PM 2Ring I was inattentive before. You did provide a way out of the dilemma and the others proved it was not possible without the feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way to solve this problem. As noted in the comments, there are no integer solutions to

$$2^x3^y=5^z$$

due to the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), so it's impossible to represent $\frac15$ using finite sums of multiples of $\frac12$ and $\frac13$.

However, we can "cheat" by using the [sum of the geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):
$$\frac15 = \frac16 + \frac1{36} + \frac1{216} + \frac1{1296} + \dots$$

We can implement this with the mergers and splitters by using one 3-splitter and three 2-splitters to do a 6-way split,
then feed one of those outputs back into the input stream. Here's a diagram:

[image: merger and splitter graph]

- src: the source
- m2: 2-way merger
- s3: 3-way splitter
- s2a, s2b, s2c: 2-way splitters
- o1-o5: the outputs